# Equal-freqency histogram with the prime number of elements

Tags: python, histogram

How do we get an equal-frequency histogram when the length of the data is a prime number?

Comment: can you give an example of the data and of the expected value?

Comment: Sure. I am working on astronomical data in which I deal with different galaxies. I want to get equal-frequency histograms for different numbers of star clusters (in a galaxy). The challenge is to find some function/loop in Python that breaks down/divides a prime-numbered array of the data into equal parts (widths of the bins could be different), simultaneously taking care of the remainder. Is it clear?

Comment: knowing what the data represents is definitely a nice bonus but what I actually need in order to help you is the data itself, I need you to copy and paste the data from your computer to this post  so I could see what it looks like and how is it stored, additionally I would want to see an example of the expected value

Comment: you should look at other questions on this site to see some examples and know what i am talking about